# .NET Regex - Find text between two characters within a single or multiple line block of text

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have been monkeying with the following regex expression:

```
(\b\*)\w+(\*\b)
```

What I wanted to do was extract

```
^vitae^
```

from

```
Nam vestibulum hendrerit justo. Quisque ^vitae^ libero magna. Curabitur pretium eros ut augue ullamcorper feugiat. Aenean blandit libero vitae nunc sodales pharetra.
```

But what I seem to get is that regex found the text in question and returns the all of the text in the sentence as opposed to just

```
^vitae^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you only want to match between ^ or any character?

Comment: any text that exists between two '^'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match any text between ^

```
@"\^([^^]*)\^")
```

//matchs ^ anything that isn't ^ and finally ^

It also matches line breaks if there are any

Answer (score 1):

What about this expression:

```
@"\^\w+\^"
```